# Looking for a CGI slideshow(?)/TV show broadcast between '99 and ~'07

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been looking for this TV show for the past few months and haven't been able to find anything. It was a CGI show that ran really early hours in the UK but I believe it was US made. The thing is it wasn't animated, the characters/background of the show were rendered digitally and looked very similar to "Gerry Anderson's New Captain Scarlet", but yeah nothing moved - all still images with a narrator over the top talking through the slides a bit like a comic book.

The main character was a man (also the narrator) I believe was stranded trying to survive on an alien planet, very dystopian, the episodes were short and aired back to back when I saw them. They used to always run post-midnight (I believe Channel 4 but could easily be wrong, the years it aired in could be slightly out too but believe it was around that time). I think the intro or outro for the program always had him falling/trying to grab hold of an edge of a chasm/cliff face in a cave and falling, this shot was dark with only light on him in the center of the shot, with more shots of him falling into the darkness beneath afterwards - I'm pretty certain this was in every episode. The main character was wearing a suit of some kind (I think), and remember there being a few episodes where he was traveling by some kind of vehicle. I also remember him looking somewhat like [Action Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Man). It might help but the narration/story felt like it was told almost in retrospect, as if he was saying "I needed to do this, so went xyz, on the way there etc.", like it was all in past tense. The only story elements I remember is him having to travel to a location for something and getting sidetracked/stranded along the way. I believe he wasn't on Earth (though could have been an apocalyptic Earth, thinking it was more likely something like Mars but it had been slightly colonised at some point).

Any help would be amazing, I've literally spent hours looking for this, to the extent of going through archived UK newspapers looking at TV schedules to try and find it. I've been through most of the posts on this forum too and haven't found anything similar. Thank you.

Comment: This is what Gerry Anderson's New Captain Scarlet looks like, it was very similar to this in CGI style: https://imgur.com/a/omsql

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Thanks I have edited in more, if I think of anything else I will add it in.

Comment: At the time you mention I think it would be channel 4 but this dosn't ring a bell with me

Comment: Which year was this broadcast?

Comment: The Dan Dare cartoon ([Youtube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5_u8EOtfbU)) was CGI in a style very like New Captain Scarlet (it was made by the same company). Though it was animated, not stills.

Comment: It sounds like he's describing an "action comic"

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for this myself. I believe it was called AFTERWORLD. Possibly you saw it on the Sci-Fi channel, and not C4.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a better answer if you could grab a few screenshots showing the matching style, since YouTube links have an unfortunate habit of disappearing.

Comment: Afterworld was on channel 4 in the UK, and it aired around the time period mentioned, and was normally on around midnight. As soon as I read the OP's original post I thought of this